# Qt static library: undefined reference to functions

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use a static lib in my new Qt project. The lib was created with Visual Studio 2015 Community edition and uses C++ 11. I have added the following lines to .pro file:

```
CONFIG += c++11

LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lRoboticArmLib
```

The file copied to its place: ../project/lib/RoboticArmLib.lib

As a second step I have added the headers to the project, but it can not see the definition of the functions.

```
mainwindow.cpp:11: error: undefined reference to RoboticArm::ArmRunner::getInstance()'
```

What else should I do to make my program work?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: run qmake? This often helps ;)

Comment: I have tried it, but it didn't help. I'll post an answer for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following. The library was built with Visual Studio C++ compiler (2015 version) and Qt 5.5 would like to build with MinGW or Visual Studio C++ 2013. (Depends on the settings and Qt version) The function name representer logic is not a standard in compilers, so MinGW and VS C++ works differently. This is the reason why MinGW or even VS 2013 C++ can not find the function definitions in a lib that compiled with another compiler, in this case VS C++ 2015.